# How do you plot specific lines from a data set?

Tags: python

I'm trying to take specific lines of data from [here](https://apps.bea.gov/iTable/iTable.cfm?ReqID=19&step=2#reqid=19&step=3&isuri=1&1921=underlying&1903=2017) in Table 2.4.5U. to graph. I just want to graph one line x the years.

The data is like this

"Line","","2018","2018","2018","2018","2019","2019","2019","2019","2020"

"Clothing and footwear",383863,392578,394919,394752,393532,399345,402273,400621,360720

"Food services",798966,816661,837949,832814,840030,859629,873775,876532,818221

"Income loss",3485,3512,3538,3558,3574,3609,3636,3665,3684

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x  = ["2018" , "2018" , "2018", "2018 " ,"2019 " , "2019 " , "2019 " ,"2019 " ,"2020 " ]

y  = np.genfromtxt("usafinalshort.txt", usecols=(3), unpack=True, delimiter=',')

plt.plot(x, y, 'ko')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: If your question relies on data, please include a minimal example (formatted as code) - just enough to represent/reproduce the promblem.  Please read [mre].

Comment: When you print `y` what do you get? maybe include that in your question.